# Python 2.7 Tkinter - Opening GUI windows from a Helper file

Tags: python, user-interface, instance, parent, self

I have 2 files. GUI.py and Helper.py.
I'm putting all of my logic in Helper.py

In Helper.py I imported GUI because I want to call a window from GUI when something happens in Helper. Is this a good way to go so far?

Now in GUI.py I have Class GUI(Frame)
and the **init**(self, parent)

The function I want to call is in the **init** ..so how would I call it from the helper file?

I tried this so far in Helper.py
import GUI
GUI = GUI.GUI()

But I get error:
TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to put self there, and I got my_class instance has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: so what is the `parent` in your `init` method? `Tkinter.Tk()` ?

Comment: To be honest not too sure. On top I have from Tkinter import * and then I have class GUI(Frame):
  
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)  
        self.parent = parent

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is something like this:

**GUI.py**

```
class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.addQuitBtn()
        self.pack()
        mainloop()

    def addQuitBtn(self):
        quit = Button(self.parent,text='QUIT',command=self.parent.quit,activeforeground='white',activebackground='red')
        quit.pack()

    def beautifulChartWindow(self):
        pass
```

So the `parent` in your `__init__` method is just an object of Tk,if you want to create the GUI and show it in other python scripts like Helper.py,use the code below:

**Helper.py**

```
import GUI
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

#What you have been stucked is how to create the GUI object.Just do it like this
#GUI = GUI.GUI(root)

#Once you got the GUI object, you can call the methods in GUI.py like this(here in file Helper.py)

#So you need to pass the GUI object that you have created before(Maybe just in the file GUI.py? You should call this method like Helper.myBeautifulChartWindow(GUI).This GUI is the object GUI,not the module GUI nor class GUI)
def myBeautifulChartWindow(MyGUIObject):
    MyGUIObject.beautifulChartWindow()
```

Comment: You misunderstood me a little I think. I want to call a window from Helper.py to GUI.py. In other words, I would like to do something like this: GUI.beautifulChartWindow() in Helper, and let that open in GUI.py

Comment: GUI.py is where I'm keeping all of my GUI stuff, Helper is all of my logic, but I want so that basically if something happens "in logic" then it calls a window in GUI.

Comment: @Richard  I think I did not misunderstand it.See my post again pls.I have modified it just now.

Comment: When I do this, I get RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop and I don't know. In GUI.py I have threading and so one thread is constantly checking the function (That's in helper) to see if any of them have been called.

Comment: Also, a brand new window opens and I don't want that either. (A blank one)... and beautifulChartWindow never opens.

Comment: @Richard Yes I know it,so you need the GUI object that you first created here,not to create a new one.

Comment: @Richard See my code one more time pls,you should pass the GUI object to file Helper.py.